# JQuery - Finding from a list of ULs, the UL with the least List items

Tags: jquery

Hi here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a div with  ID="columns", in this example I have 3 columns, but there may be more or less... I'm using JQuery to add list items dynamically.

```
<div id="columns">
   <ul id="column1" class="column">
   </ul>
   <ul id="column2" class="column">
   </ul>
   <ul id="column3" class="column">
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using the following to get a list of UL's

```
var columns = $("#columns ul");
```

Now, what I'd like to do is when adding a dynamic LI I'd like to loop through these columns and add it to the column with the least amount of list items...

I'm getting the count of items for specific columns using the following

```
var countColumn1 = $("#column1").children().length;
```

So I'm nearly there, just need a little assistance traversing through the dynamic var columns and then returning the UL with the shortest length.

Hope this makes sense.

Tanks!

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `columns.sort()` method with a custom compare function:

```
function compareColumnLength(c1, c2) {
    return $('li', c1).length - $('li', c2).length;
}
```

Then append your new list item to `columns.first()`

**EDIT** More code:

```
var shortest = $("#columns ul").sort(compareColumnLength).first();
var item = $('<li/>').appendTo(shortest);
```

**EDIT** See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sinsedrix/DYT5G/

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work for my scenario (I actually also have nested UL's and LI's...

Comment: Actually, no.. shortest only seems to work if there are no items in a list, otherwise it returns 'undefined'

Comment: Same issue, there are nested UL's and LIked up... I'm googling ;)

Comment: gotit!  $("#columns > ul").sort(compareColumnLength).first();

Answer (score 1):

how about this...

```
var columns = $("#columns ul");

var shortest = null;

for(i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
  var column = $(columns[i]);

  if(shortest == null){
     shortest = column;
  }
  else if(column.children().length < shortest.children().length){
     shortest = column;
  }
}

//you can now use shortest as the column with the least items
if(shortest != null)//check if at least one column found
{
   //here shortest will be a jquery object for the ul with the least items
}
```

NOTE: If more than more column has the same least number of items, the first found one will be referenced

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. OK so this seems to work, but still battling with something. The list items have nested UL's and LI's, how do I only check the LI's under the top UL's? Sure there must be a quick fix... Much appreciated!

Comment: Got it, $("#columns > ul");
 if I'm not mistaken... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
  var ulWithMinItems = null;
    $("#columns ul").each(function(index){
       if(index == 0)
            ulWithMinItems = this;
       if($(this).children().length <= $(ulWithMinItems).children().length)
            ulWithMinItems = this;
    });

//ulWithMinItems will hold your ul with most children.
```

Comment: hmmm, that two answers now providing the longest... is it just me who can see the word "shortest"? :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wngchng87/s7wTg/

```
var ul_with_least_li = $("#columns ul:first");
var least_li_count = ul_with_least_li.children("li").length;


$.each($("#columns ul"), function(i, item){
if ($(item).children("li").length < least_li_count) {
    ul_with_least_li = $(item);
    least_li_count = ul_with_least_li.children("li").length;
}
});


console.log(ul_with_least_li);
console.log(least_li_count);

ul_with_least_li.append("<li>I have the least LIs</li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little example that will add a text to the `ul` with the lowest length: http://jsfiddle.net/x8Up8/13/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function(){
        var len = 0;
        var theobj = null;
        $("#columns ul").each(function(){
            var cur = $(this).children().length;
            if (cur < len || len == 0) {
                len = cur;
                theobj = $(this);
            }
        });
        theobj.append('<li>text</li>');
    });
});

<div id="columns">
   <ul id="column1" class="column">
       <li>text</li>
       <li>text</li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="column2" class="column">
       <li>text</li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="column3" class="column">
       <li>text</li>
       <li>text</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<button>Add text</button>
```